# Prove the inconsistency of this definition of limit

Tags: calculus, limits, logic, definition, solution-verification

I want to prove that the following fake definition of limit doesn't capture the property that $f(x)$ tends to infinity as $x$ does :

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow +\infty} f(x) = +\infty \iff \forall M > 0 \exists X > 0\mid( f(x) > M \implies x > X ) $$

If I take a strictly increasing and continuos function so that $\lim_{x\rightarrow +\infty} f(x) = a $ with $a \in R$ then the definition is surely satisfied when $M < a$ . However, if I take an $M > a $ then $f(x)>M $ is always false.

Because implication is always true in this case , can I say to have proven that the definition is wrong ( because the definition would mean also the same of  $\lim_{x\rightarrow +\infty} f(x) = a $ ) ?

Comment: you have not quantify $x$.

Comment: Sorry I am a bit confused. Are you going to prove the statement in your post is false? But the definition you are using for limit is not quite true, say, $\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x) = \infty$ means that for any $M > 0$, there exists $X > 0$ such that $x > X \implies f(x) > M$.

Comment: yes it is false , I want to prove that this definition can't be a good definition

Comment: What do you mean by "inconsistent" or "good"? The proposed definition is a perfectly good definition of a property of the function $f$, it just doesn't capture the property that $f(x)$ tends to $\infty$ as $x$ does.

Comment: I want to mean what you said  , I edit for clarity

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For example, $f(x) = x^2$ doesn't satisfy your definition.

On the other hand $f(x) = 1 - e^{-x}$ satisfies your definition  but $\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x) \ne +\infty$.

Comment: thank for your answer... but why does't $f(x)= x^2 $ satisfy the definition?

Comment: Consider what happens if $x$ is negative

Comment: ah right , I was thinking about to just half parabola, thanks!